# Can the selected columns affect the row order in a MySQL result?

Tags: mysql, select

I've got to queries that are "identical" except that in the one query I only retrieve one column from the table whereas in the other one I retrieve several columns from the same table. Otherwise everything is identical. For some reason, the order is not exactly the same in the results from the two queries. How can this be?

These are the two queries:

```
SELECT b.bruker_id, b.poeng_j + b.poeng_ss + b.poeng_u + b.poeng_n + b.poeng_s + b.poeng_f + b.poeng_v AS orderColumn
FROM brukere b
JOIN soknad s ON b.bruker_id = s.bruker_id
WHERE s.t_start_y =2013
AND s.t_start_s =0
AND YEAR( NOW( ) ) - b.aar >30
AND YEAR( NOW( ) ) - b.aar <40
ORDER BY orderColumn DESC 
LIMIT 10 ;

SELECT b.bruker_id, b.poeng_j + b.poeng_ss + b.poeng_u + b.poeng_n + b.poeng_s + b.poeng_f + b.poeng_v AS orderColumn, b.etternavn, b.fornavn, YEAR( NOW( ) ) - b.aar AS alder, b.poeng_j, b.poeng_ss, b.poeng_u, b.poeng_n, b.poeng_s, b.poeng_f, b.poeng_v, b.kjonn
FROM brukere b
JOIN soknad s ON b.bruker_id = s.bruker_id
WHERE s.t_start_y =2013
AND s.t_start_s =0
AND YEAR( NOW( ) ) - b.aar >30
AND YEAR( NOW( ) ) - b.aar <40
ORDER BY orderColumn DESC 
LIMIT 10 ;
```

The first query returns:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| bruker_id | orderColumn |
+-----------+-------------+
|        92 |          29 |
|       271 |          28 |
|       645 |          28 |
|       323 |          27 |
|       487 |          27 |
|        58 |          27 |
|        76 |          27 |
|       289 |          26 |
|       759 |          26 |
|       128 |          26 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

And the scond query returns:

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+-------+------------+------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+-------+
| bruker_id | orderColumn | etternavn | fornavn  | alder | poeng_j | poeng_ss | poeng_u | poeng_n | poeng_s | poeng_f | poeng_v | kjonn |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+-------+------------+------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+-------+
|        92 |          29 | Tonheim   | Kine     |    33 |          4 |               16 |                3 |           0 |         0 |               6 |          0 |     1 |
|       645 |          28 | Saue      | Laila    |    36 |          8 |               16 |                0 |           0 |         0 |               4 |          0 |     1 |
|       271 |          28 | Grønnevik | Karl     |    38 |          8 |               16 |                0 |           0 |         0 |               4 |          0 |     0 |
|        76 |          27 | Tornes    | Kristina |    39 |          5 |               16 |                0 |           0 |         0 |               6 |          0 |     1 |
|       487 |          27 | Smestad   | Tonje    |    34 |          8 |               16 |                0 |           0 |         0 |               0 |          3 |     1 |
|        58 |          27 | Torjussen | Linn     |    35 |          8 |               16 |                0 |           0 |         0 |               0 |          3 |     1 |
|       323 |          27 | Gillebo   | Tore     |    31 |          5 |               16 |                0 |           0 |         0 |               6 |          0 |     0 |
|       759 |          26 | Sætren    | Grete    |    36 |          4 |               16 |                0 |           0 |         0 |               6 |          0 |     1 |
|       289 |          26 | Gjersøe   | Torbjørn |    37 |          4 |               16 |                0 |           0 |         0 |               6 |          0 |     0 |
|       339 |          26 | Gjøen     | Fredrik  |    34 |          4 |               16 |                0 |           0 |         0 |               6 |          0 |     0 |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+-------+------------+------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+-------+
```

As you can see, the order is not the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a column to each SELECT first

```
b.poeng_j + b.poeng_ss + b.poeng_u + b.poeng_n + b.poeng_s + b.poeng_f + b.poeng_v AS orderColumn
```

Then change the queries to be `ORDER BY orderColumn`

You will then be able to see clearly *what* it is ordering by.  You will probably then see that some of the rows have the same value in orderColumn, and so the ordering may not be consistent without having a second ORDER BY criteria, i.e. `ORDER BY orderColumn, bruker_id`

Using your second query I would end up with

```
SELECT 
    b.bruker_id, 
    b.etternavn, 
    b.fornavn, 
    YEAR( NOW( ) ) - b.aar AS alder, 
    b.poeng_j, b.poeng_ss, 
    b.poeng_u, 
    b.poeng_n, b.poeng_s, 
    b.poeng_f, 
    b.poeng_v, 
    b.kjonn,
    (b.poeng_j + b.poeng_ss + b.poeng_u + b.poeng_n + b.poeng_s + b.poeng_f + b.poeng_v) AS orderColumn
FROM brukere b
JOIN soknad s ON b.bruker_id = s.bruker_id
WHERE s.t_start_y =2013
    AND s.t_start_s =0
    AND YEAR( NOW( ) ) - b.aar >30
    AND YEAR( NOW( ) ) - b.aar <40
ORDER BY orderColumn DESC, b.bruker_id ASC 
LIMIT 10 ;
```

In your sample data, bruker_id 645 and 271 both would have an orderColumn value of 28.

Comment: good idea! I did, and as you can see many of the values are equal for the orderColumn variable. could this be the reason? An if so, why is the order different between the two queries?

Comment: The order, by default, depends on the order in which MySQL has stored them internally.  In theory the same query would return the same data however it's not 100% certain.  If therefore the order of results matters, then it is better to add in an additional ORDER criteria or two to ensure that any duplicates in one ORDER BY clause have a backup ORDER BY to ensure the order is consistent.

Comment: For your specific example I can't advise as to precisely *why* MySQl swapped some rows around however I would suspect it to be related to the specific columns being selected.  It may be that the first query is based off the row order in `soknad` as all you are selecting is the PK from `brukere`, however the second relies on the ordering in `brukere` more.  I can't offer much more than a guess on that though.

Comment: ok, so you would recommend adding i.e. bruker_id as the last order by statement to ensure identical results??

Comment: It seems like a good option, yes, as it is the PK and so will be unique and therefore you can be 100% certain that ordering will be consistent.